# Compiler error in my inheritance code in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I was learning about inheritance in C++. So whenever a object of a class is created a constructor is called.
And constructor is used to initialize the class variables.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    protected:
        int x;
    public:
        
        Base(int a): x(a)
        {
            cout<<"Base"<<endl;
        }
};
class Derived: public Base
{
    private:
        int y;
    public:
                                      
        Derived(int b):y(b)
        {
            cout<<"Derived"<<endl;
        }
    
        void print()
        {
            cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    Derived d(20);
    d.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Since here I am creating object of base class and calling print function on this. So I should get output.
But my code is giving compiler error, why?
Can anyone help me understanding this?

Comment: Where, exactly, do you think the `Derived` constructor is setting the value of `x`?

Comment: Is the compliler error message secrete?

Comment: @S.M. No matching function for call to 'Base::Base()'

Comment: also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on a solution proposed below?

Answer (score 5):

When you construct your `Derived` object in the `Derived(int b): y(b) {}`, the `Base` part of this object has to be constructed too. Since you do provide a constructor for `Base` which takes an `int` there won't be an [implicitly defined default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor) in the `Base` *(even if it was, the `int` data member `x` would have an undefined value*). Thus, there's no way to construct the `d` in the `Derived d(20)` using your definitions for both classes.

You may look toward the following approach:

```
// Inside Base class:
// We provide a default constructor
// As well as one that takes an int
Base(int a = 0): x(a) {} 

// Inside Derived class:
// We supply a value for the Base and a value for the Derived part
Derived(int b, int d): Base(b), y(d) {} 

// Inside main():
Derived d(20, 30);
d.print();
// Prints: 20 30
```

When we have a default constructor provided for the `Base`, we can even do like so, and it will compile:

```
// Base part will be default constructed
Derived(int b): y(b) {} 
// ...Prints: 0 20
```

Here, the `Base` part of a `Derived` instance will have a **default value**, while the `Derived` part will have a value **explicitly supplied** to it. In general, this would probably be a **mistake**, *of logical nature*. Nevertheless, it will compile.